# grep a file from one unix machine to another unix machine

Tags: perl, unix

I have 2 Unix machines A and B. I Have input string in Machine A and need to pass the input string to machine B and grep in /home/ram directory and find a file ,display the content of that file  in Machine A.I am using perl script and I know the sftp will get the file from one system to another
    sftp username@Machine2 after that using "get filename" will bring the file to machine1 and I am using the following code to display the file content
    system("/bin/grep -l '$input_string' /home/ajay > $file");
    open (INPUT, "){
    print "$_";
    }

Thanks,
Viki

Comment: So, what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ssh to get this done

for example, to get the remote file content,

```
$ssh 10.2.7.99 '/bin/cat filename.txt' > file1.txt
```

for your problem use the find command to search the file, if file found use the cat to print the file